# What does “falls into clover with a lock” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There was the following passage in New York Times’s (March 25) article that came under the headline, “Donald, This I will tell you,” written by Maureen Dowd:

> “As The Times’s chief Washington correspondent Carl Hulse put it, the
>   G.O.P. **falls into clover with a lock** on the White House and both
>   houses of Congress, and what’s the first thing it does? Slip on a
>   banana peel. Incompetence Inc.”

https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/25/opinion/sunday/donald-this-i-will-tell-you.html?action

What does "fall into clover with a lock" mean? Is it a well-received turn of phrase? I googled for a definition of the phrase with no avail.

Comment: They are two entirely different phrases.  Look up the idiom "in clover" and figurative meanings of "lock".

Comment: "GOP falls into clover" sounds as if GOP is very lucky with the Bill's trainwreck, which I cannot still make out. Why "with lock," is  GOP in "prosperous circumstances" as Q23us explains?.

Comment: The "fall into clover" refers to the "lock on the White House and both houses of Congress" -- in other words, they have complete control of the government.  The only problem is that they don't know what to do with it, leading to the problem with the TrumpCare bill.

Comment: ＠Hot Licks. I think I could make out finally.thank to your last comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

To be in clover is to enjoy prosperous circumstances, through effort and/or luck. (I believe the writer's use of "fall" in this case emphasizes luck over effort.)

To have a lock on something is to own or control it completely. Part of the connotation is to deny (lock out) someone else's efforts to control the thing.

Here, "with a lock" is not part of the idiom "falls into clover." Rephrased: "With a lock on the White House and both houses of Congress, the G.O.P. falls into clover ..."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56058/discussion-on-answer-by-q23-us-what-does-falls-into-clover-with-a-lock-mean).